# Uniquely identify a process in node.js

Tags: node.js, unix

What values available in node.js combined create a unique ID for each process on each server in node.js? Right now, I only know how to obtain the process id.

Comment: What's wrong with the process id?

Comment: What do you mean by each server on node.js ? Are you running multiple node servers.

Comment: i could have a multi-core server running multiple processes (per core). i could also have multiple of these. process id is fine, but it's not unique.

Comment: Multi processes have different process ids

Comment: tell me something i don't know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

node.js is a single-threaded server. It will only use one CPU core (spawned processes can use other cores) and `process.pid` would suffice for identifying the node process on system. If you run multiple node.js servers, then each will have different process.pid.

If you want a single node server to take advantage of multi-core CPU, you must run node.js in cluster. Use `cluster` package http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html.

It forks main thread into a number of worker threads, which communicate with each other using IPC (Inter-Process Communication). Each worker utilizes a CPU core. To get id for each worker you can use `worker.id` http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_id

**Edit: Adding from comment**

The answer depends on the size / range of possible values. On a LAN hostname, IP and pid may be enough. Also each server can have multiple NIC and IP it can listen to. Check this using `app.address() { address: '192.1.168.5', family: 'IPv4', port: 3000 }`

Comment: my question isn't about pid or processes. that i know. my question is how to make a unique ID for each process. PID isn't unique enough. maerics has the right idea.

Comment: If you are trying to generate some identifier that can differentiate processes on machines. It depends on the size / range of possible values. On a LAN hostname ,IP and pid may be enough. Also each server can have multiple NIC and IP it can listen to. Check this using app.address() { address: '192.1.168.5', family: 'IPv4', port: 3000 }

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what your requirements are but you could do a hash of (hostname + pid + timestamp):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const os = require('os');

const parts = [os.hostname(), process.pid, Date.now()];
const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(parts.join(''));

hash.digest('hex'); // "56f0dec9b403c5aa19827326555d6a5b"
```

Comment: what other requirements would make this function different?

Comment: NOTE: This only works if you don't need the id to be durable across your master node process restarts...because of new Date. I'm looking for a solution that would be unique on the OS.